# My VB 2005 Macros No Longer Work

Tags: vb.net, macros, visual-studio-2005

I have a small set of macros I use with my IDE for commenting, and other minor repeatable tasks. I've been using these macros for a few years.

Recently they just stopped working. I'm not getting any errors, but they appear to not be executing. I've tried opening the Macro IDE and setting breakpoints on the first line of the macros, but nothing happens.

I've been dealing with this problem for a few weeks now, so I have reboot a few times since then. I've tried repairing the IDE, but still nothing works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Marshall

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Microsoft KB928209](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928209) and [Microsoft KB906763](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906763)?

They both sound similar to the issue your are describing.

Comment: The first link goes to a blank page, and as for the second, I have the Compact Framework 2.0. Repairing it did not help. I have Framework 3.5 and 4.5.1, both of which I tried repairing. Did not help.